# Response is dynamic: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 149

Tags: android, gson

Here is my GSON response and my response is dynamic.

Note: I can't change response

```
{   "soapBody": {
    "GenerateProposalResponse": {
      "GenerateProposalResult": {
        "POL_SYS_ID": "102123205",
        "PROPOSAL_NO": "10083\/31\/20\/P\/0004354",
        "VehicleIDV": {

        },
        "ERROR_DESC": "Proposal created successfully......!",
        "ERROR_CODE": "0",
        "CoverDtlList": {
          "CoverDtl": [
            {
              "CoverDesc": "BASIC TP COVER",
              "Premium": "752",
              "Type": {

              }
            },
            {
              "CoverDesc": "GR36A-PA FOR OWNER DRIVER",
              "Premium": "315",
              "Type": "ADD"
            },
            {
              "CoverDesc": "TP TOTAL",
              "Premium": "1067",
              "Type": {

              }
            },
            {
              "CoverDesc": "TOTAL PREMIUM",
              "Premium": "1067",
              "Type": {

              }
            },
            {
              "CoverDesc": "IGST",
              "Premium": "192",
              "Type": "ADD"
            },
            {
              "CoverDesc": "TOTAL AMOUNT",
              "Premium": "1259",
              "Type": {

              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }   } }
```

many time, I got "VehicleIDV": "1230" and many time I got "VehicleIDV":{}

> W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 149 path $.soapBody.GenerateProposalResponse.GenerateProposalResult.VehicleIDV

Here is my function

```
public void getShri(final Context mContext, String id) {
    ApiClient restClient = new ApiClient(mContext);
    restClient.setCommunication();
    ApiInterface apiService = restClient.getApiService();

    try {
        Call call = apiService.getShri(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Shri>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Shri> call, Response<Shri> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Shri commonResponse = response.body();
                    ((onRequestCompleteCallBackListener) mContext).
                            onResponse(commonResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Shri> call, Throwable t) {
                //onResponse(t);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is apiInterface code

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("shri.php")
    Call<Shri> getShri(@Field("id") String id);
```

Comment: Please post your code too

Comment: Check that API is working properly in Postman then according to response change your model class.

Comment: @NileshPanchal many time, I got  ```"VehicleIDV": "1230"```  and many time I got ```"VehicleIDV":{}```

Comment: The solution is having customs ```TypeAdaptor``` for ```VehicleIDV```. If you need more help please add you model class to code the type adaptor you need.